# sum database values grouped by a second table keys

Tags: javascript, sqlite, group-by

I have the following tables

billpayments table where barcode is unique

```
barcode    amount    receiptno
123        10        1
124        20        1
125        10        2
126        10        2
127        20        3
```

bill table with unique barcode

```
barcode    buildingcode  
123        1001
124        1001
125        1002
126        1002
127        1002
```

I want to display the sum of amount grouped by building code like that

```
buildingcode     sum amount
1001             30
1002             40
```

I use the following code but I only group by receiptno

```
t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, SUM(amount) AS myamount, receiptno FROM billpayments WHERE receiptno > 0 GROUP BY receiptno', 
        [], function(t, resultcollect) {

            len = resultcollect.rows.length;

            function dummy(i){
                var row = resultcollect.rows.item(i);
                t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, buildingcode FROM bill WHERE barcode = ?', 
                    [row.barcode], function(t, collectaddress) {
                        mybill = collectaddress.rows.item(0);

                        if (row.receiptno != 0){
                            items.push('<tr><td>' + row.receiptno + '</td><td>' + mybill.buildingcode + '</td><td><font color="blue">' + row.myamount.toFixed(2) + '</font></td><td></td></tr>');
                        }
                    });
            }

            for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                dummy(i);
            }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT buildingcode, SUM(amount)
FROM bill JOIN billpayments ON bill.barcode = billpayments.barcode
GROUP BY buildingcode
```